# How to auto-refresh Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Solution Explorer after changing branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Git for source control. I have a master and a "work" branch for the Solution. 
I have deleted 5 files from the solution on work branch, those files still exist on master.

I'm using VS2012 Ultimate.

I set up the project in VS2012 from master. Everything in Solution Explorer is fine.

I then git checkout -b work to swap branches from master to work.
On the file system the 5 files are gone.
In Solution Explorer they still remain.

What's the best way to keep Solution Explorer in track with what has happened in the file system? I am a total VS2012 newbie so if I'm missing the obvious I apologise.
I know I could manually exclude them but that won't scale for big change sets. Also I am a little scared additions or updates might not have sync'd either.

In Eclipse I'd just Refresh and it'd sync. VS2012 should do the same?

Comment: Installing the Visual Studio Tools for Git should notice that you've switched branches and update Solution Explorer:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Comment: Hey thanks :) I had Git Tools installed, version 1. Yesterday I upgraded to latest (along with CTP2) and now switching branches will update Solution Explorer (but you have to Close the Solution first otherwise you get many error dialogs about null objects)

Comment: Oh no, really?  I'm not sure that's expected.  Can you follow up with me off-line (my email address is `ethomson@microsoft.com`) so that I can make sure this feedback gets routed to the appropriate people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Edward Thomson points out, upgrading to latest Visual Studio Tools for Git provides this functionality. Thanks Edward :)